# Get underlying Actor from ActorRef with the Akka Test Kit

Tags: scala, testing, akka, actor

Is there any way to get the underlying Actor from an ActorRef using the Akka Actor Test Kit?

I'm aware of `TestActorRef`, but I can not use them in my tests, since the Actors are instantiated deep in my application. All I can get is their reference. Testing everything with messaging would be a pain.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you're attempting is a very bad anti-pattern in Akka. The entire purpose of Actors and their interaction is the isolation - hiding the Actor instance from the outside.

If you were to inspect the Actor instance you'd keep running into race conditions, as such access is not protected by the Actor guarantee of "as-if" single-threadedness.

I strongly suggest building and composing your actors in such a way that you're able to test the interactions they're modeling, and not have to inspect their internal state directly. For example, you could have methods that ask the actor to give it's internal state etc. Point is, that then it's made on purpose and the state that you expose can be different from the one that's actually kept in the instance (easier to evolve and change internal representation).

Comment: I strongly disagree with you. Having a scheduler as an `Actor` for example would be clearly a pain to test its (complex) internal state through messaging. This would mean a lot of boilerplate messaging code, and I think the `TestActorRef` has been invented for a reason. The only problem is that to have a full-blown integration test with `TestActorRef`, one would actually mess with the deployment of the actors, to acquire a `TestActorRef`. As you mention yourself, having methods to export internal immutable state would be great while testing.

Comment: @Dyin you could provide some kind of actor creation factory, that you can override in your tests, so they create Test actors instead of real ones, then you have your `TestActorRef`